# Google trying to index child theme files

Tags: plugins, themes, child-theme

I have created a child theme as per Wordpress recommendation to customize my site.It is working as expected however, I am seeing some `Server error (5xx)` reports in the Google search console.

It seems that google is trying to index all the php files under the child theme.I am not sure what is reason behind this or how can I stop google to not index anything in the child theme.

I did some research and few people are suggesting to use

`if ( ! defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) {
    header( 'HTTP/1.0 403 Forbidden' ); 
    die();
}`
to block direct access to these files.Is there any other solution to handle this issue in Wordpress?

```
**Edit**
Here is the style.css
/*
Theme Name:Child
Theme URI: 
Template: xxx
Author: Themes
Author URI: 
Description:description
Tags: blog
Version: 1.300.08.1520202511
Updated: 2018-03-04 22:28:31
*/

<?php
// Exit if accessed directly
if ( !defined( 'ABSPATH' ) ) exit;

// BEGIN ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION
// AUTO GENERATED - Do not modify or remove comment markers above or below:

// END ENQUEUE PARENT ACTION


// Custom Code

function theme_enqueue_styles() {
    wp_enqueue_style( 'custom-style', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/css/jdj-custom.css' );
}
//add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'theme_enqueue_styles', 200 );

/**
 *  For Home page span tag
*/
```

Comment: Did you copy the full theme to the child directory?  As default the Child theme should contain only style.css with the Template: tag and a functions.php.  Do not copy from the original main theme, that will not work.  Update the question with a copy the first 20 lines of you main style.css and your functions.php. And I will help more.

Comment: @SEODEVS: added required information.I have only copied the files which are customized in the original theme.